# How to make an object do subdivision AFTER boolean'd by another object?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, boolean-modifier

What I do:

1. Create object A
2. Create object B
3. Add boolean modifier to A, make difference with B
4. Add subdivision surface modifier to B

What I expect:

1. Blender do boolean operation between A and B first
2. Then Blender do subdivision surface to B

But instead:

1. Blender do subdivision surface to B FIRST
2. AFTER THAT Blender do boolean between A and B

which create a smooth boolean result for A, which is not what I wanted. I want a blocky boolean result.

I figured out a solution: Apply boolean to A first, then add subdivision surface to B.

But I don't like it. Why?

1. I DO NOT want to apply boolean modifier to A because I need to edit B.
2. I DO want to make B look smooth by adding subdivision surface.

I know how to adjust the execution order of modifiers of a single object by simply dragging them, but I don't know how to adjust execution order of modifiers across multiple objects. Can I do this in blender? If I can, how?

Comment: Your expectation is incorrrct. Blender does it correctly. Ofcourse your end result for B is subdivided which is used as diff to A. Why do you need to subdivide B after the boolean? Just create a copy of B and call it C which u can apply subdivision on. Please also provide some pictures of what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifier order applies to a single object only. If you modify one object with modifiers, it has nothing to do with modifier order on any other objects.

You can simply Duplicate Linked your B object (Alt+D) and have 2 objects sharing the same data(geometry). Now you can Boolean your A object with B, hide B and have the copy of B that you can apply whatever modifiers without effecting the Boolean operation, but if you edit the object's geometry, then it changes in the original B that is still interreacting in the Boolean operation.